# store session variable and access it through javascript?

Tags: javascript, sessions

In drupal, how do you store/read session variables? Also, how can i access a stored session variable through javascript?

I'm trying to store whether if a user has closed my modal or not so it doesn't pop up for another day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accessing a session variable in Drupal is not different from how it is done with plain PHP: with `$_SESSION`.

As for reading them with JavaScript, it is enough to use code similar to the following one.

```php
// PHP
drupal_add_js(array('myModule' => array('key' => $_SESSION['key'])), 'setting');
```

```js
// JavaScript
key = Drupal.settings.myModule.key;
```